# PHP Form Validation Using empty() Function

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm trying to learn PHP. I wanted to validate the form I have but couldn't achieve what I want.

1. I want to validate the `username` field if it's empty or not using `empty()` function. But if it's false, do not display the username yet.
2. Validate the `password` field if empty or not using the same function.
3. What I want is to display the `username` and `password` only if both fields are not empty. Here's what I have so far.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Form Validation</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php
   $username = $password = '';
   $username_err = $password_err = '';
   if (isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
   if (empty($_POST['username']))
   {
   $username_err = "Username is required<br>";
   }
   else {  
   $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
   if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$username))
   {
   $username_err = "Only letters are required<br>";
   }
   }
   if (empty($_POST['password']))
   {
   $password_err = "Password is required<br>";
   }
   else {
   $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
   }
   }
   ?>

     <form id="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"                 method="post">
     Enter your username:<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"> 
   <span><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
   Enter your password:<input type="password" name="password">
   <span><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>

   <h2>Results</h2><br><br>

   <?php echo $username, '<br>', $password, '<br>'; ?>
      </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: try using `trim()` before putting in empty() function like this `empty(trim($_POST['username']))`

Comment: if( !(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) ))       echo $username, '<br>', $password, '<br>';

Comment: Be careful with empty() function: values like an empty string "", a numeric zero "0", "false" or "null" will also return true because it is considered as an empty value. Make sure your input fields cannot be empty or contain any of the values explained above or you will receive unexpected results from the function. There are several ways to achive to check if a value is empty for sure. I prefer to use if(strlen($input) > 0) { ... }

Comment: What if you convert the incoming $_POST data to integer, can you still use strlen()?